# Highcharts min max limits separated?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using min and max options in the x axis to filter the data with given from and to dates
BUT
I want the result chart to be separated from the parent chart
example
[image]

the big chart is the original one, the min max limits forming the blue X range
the result is the 3 points + the two lines out of the yellow box

I want only the 3 points connected together, I need it only to draw the points inside the interval nothing more

[another example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/max-200/)  I want it to ignore septemper point, and draw line between august and october

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        max: 200
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
```

});

Comment: But how to extract data from parent? Do you have two separate charts, paretna and partial?

Comment: No I don't,it's only one chart, I want to apply the filter with date effect on it, using min and max

Comment: So you zoom at this part and then you would like to don't have lines in the edges?

Comment: something like that, yes

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible.